# Have picture based questions increased after ChatGPT?

Tags: support, questions, data-explorer

I'm seeing too much increase of picture-based questions after ChatGPT. Is there any data available to prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/1724639#graph) to include the moving average as well:

```
select eomonth(creationdate) [month]
     , sum(case when patindex('%<img%', body) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) [# posts w/image] 
     , avg ( sum(case when patindex('%<img%', body) > 0 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / 
             count(*) *100 ) 
        OVER(ORDER BY eomonth(creationdate)
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) [moving 2 month avg]
     , avg ( sum(case when patindex('%<img%', body) > 0 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / 
             count(*) *100 ) 
        OVER(ORDER BY eomonth(creationdate)
        ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) [moving 6 month avg]
from posts
where posttypeid = 1
and creationdate < eomonth(dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))
group by eomonth(creationdate)
order by eomonth(creationdate)
```

resulting in this graph:

[image: graph with 2 and 6 month moving average, trending slightly up]

I conclude there is a trending up but that trend doesn't seem to have increased over the last months.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated each Sunday.
Do try the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio)
Say "Hi!" in [Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/1724635#graph) is a SEDE query showing the % of questions that have a picture in them. ChatGPT became available late November / early December last year, but I don't see a significant pattern from then on.

[image]

Now, there's a difference between picture-based questions and questions that have a picture in them, but it might help if you provide some examples. From time to time, we see certain trends here, e.g. the [Riley riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affix-riddle), and you might see more of the same puzzles during such a period.